How do I open my own database that I've prebundled in React Native expo?
I'm using sqlite legacy on React Native expo to attempt to open a database file and make use of it that I've put in the assets folder named "jm_dict.db".
        const jmDictDbFileName = "../assets/jm_dict.db";
    
        // Function to open the JMDict database 
        async function openJMDictDatabase() {
          try {
            const db = SQLite.openDatabase(jmDictDbFileName);
            console.log("JMDict Database opened successfully");
            return db;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error opening JMDict database:", error);
            throw error;
          }
        }

However, when I try to pass the path into the .openDatabase() area , I get the following error:

ERROR  Transaction error : [Error: Calling the 'exec' function has failed→ Caused by: Could not open database]ERROR  Error fetching word data: [Error: Calling the 'exec' function has failed→ Caused by: Could not open database]

The error is logged from the function below.
    // Function to fetch a word and its definition by the word itself (kanji or kana)
    export const fetchWordByWordText = async (searchWord) => {. 
      try {
        console.log("Attempting to fetch word:", searchWord);
        const jmDictDb = await openJMDictDatabase();
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          jmDictDb.transaction(
            (tx) => {
              tx.executeSql(
                `SELECT 
                JMDictWord.word_id, 
                Kanji.text AS kanji_text, 
                Kana.text AS kana_text, 
                Sense.gloss AS definition
              FROM 
                JMDictWord
              LEFT JOIN 
                Kanji ON JMDictWord.word_id = Kanji.word_id 
               LEFT JOIN 
                Kana ON JMDictWord.word_id = Kana.word_id
              LEFT JOIN 
                Sense ON JMDictWord.word_id = Sense.word_id
              WHERE 
                Kanji.text = ? OR Kana.text = ?
              LIMIT 1;`,
                [searchWord, searchWord],
                (_, results) => {
                  console.log("SQL query executed successfully");
              const rows = results.rows;
              if (rows.length > 0) {
                const row = rows.item(0);
                const fetchedResult = {
                  word_id: row.word_id,
                  kanji: row.kanji_text,
                  kana: row.kana_text,
                  definition: row.definition,
                };
                console.log("Fetched result:", fetchedResult);
                resolve(fetchedResult);
              } else {
                console.log("No results found");
                resolve(null);
              }
            },
            (_, error) => {
              console.error("Error executing SQL:", error);
              reject(error);
            }
          );
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error("Transaction error:", error);
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error opening JMDict database:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

I've tried copying and pasting the database file into node_modules and other places where the database file can be read and it still doesn't work.`

See the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite-legacy/#importing-an-existing-database.
